# Check if row with value already exists in SQLite table

Tags: android, sqlite

How do I check to see if row with a particular value already exists in a SQLite table?

My table has a String "name" column. I would like to check out if a particular name already exists in the another table row. I am still learning SQLite, but I think it is possible to do this with the cursor.

Comment: I editted primarily the grammar to make it more clear what was being asked. I also removed 'Java', 'Android', 'row', and 'exists' tags -- the first two because this is about SQLite and not the Java/Android implementations; the last two because they're nonsense. If this question really is about something Java or Android specific, please update your question with Java/Android code that is specific to such an implementation rather than just SQLite in general

Answer (score 2):

If you have a UNIQUE constraint on the `name` column, you can use INSERT OR IGNORE (or [insertWithOnConflict()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int%29) in Android) to insert a row only if it does not already exist.

In the general case, to check whether a row exists, you have to run a SELECT query.
However, there is a [helper function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) for counting rows:

```java
boolean nameExists(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = ...;
    long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,
                    "MyTable", "name = ?", new String[] { name });
    return count > 0;
}
```